# Tradingview Strategy Tester - Stoploss is not triggered correctly

Tags: pine-script

I have an issue with the strategy tester, because sometimes the stoploss is not triggered correctly.

First of all here is the code:

```
ATR_SL = atr(input(defval=14,title="ATR_SL",type=input.integer))[1]
Multip_ATR_SL = input(defval=2,title="Multip_ATR_SL",type=input.float)
TakeProfitMultiplier = input(defval=1.3,title="TakeProfitMultiplier",type=input.float)
PctStop = input(defval=2, title="% of Risk to Starting Equity Use to Size Positions") / 100
Longstop_abs =low - ATR_SL * Multip_ATR_SL
LongTP_abs = close+(close - Longstop_abs)*TakeProfitMultiplier
LongTP_Pips = (LongTP_abs - close)/syminfo.mintick
Longstop_Pips = (close-Longstop_abs)/syminfo.mintick

initialCapital = strategy.equity

plot(close, "close")
plot(LongTP_abs, "LongTP_abs")
plot(LongTP_Pips, "LongTP_Pips")
plot(Longstop_abs, "Longstop_abs")
plot(Longstop_Pips, "Longstop_Pips")


if crossoverBull
        LongDiffSL = abs(close - Longstop_abs)
        LongPositionSize = (initialCapital * PctStop) / LongDiffSL
        strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long, qty=LongPositionSize)
        strategy.exit("Exit", from_entry="Enter Long",loss=Longstop_Pips, profit=LongTP_Pips)
```

As you can see, the SL is set with the value Longstop_Pips:

```
strategy.exit("Exit", from_entry="Enter Long",loss=Longstop_Pips, profit=LongTP_Pips)
```

This works correctly e.g. for the following example:

[image]

However, in other situations the SL is triggered wrongly and much too early:

[image]

As you can see the value Longstop_Pips and Longstop_abs are matching with the long position marker like in the working example above. However, the SL is triggered much earlier. This happened several times when I checked the trades manually.
Those are the other settings:

[image]

Has anybody experienced the same issue? Is there something wrong with my code?
Sometimes also the take profit is wrong even though the values in the script are correct.

I would really appreciate your help, because the strategy tester is generally awesome!

======

EDIT 31.08.2022

In the following is the complete code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Stochastic Cross Alarm Strategy", default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=10, initial_capital=1000, overlay = true, format=format.price, precision=2)


//Stochastics variables
periodK = input(14, title="Stoch_K", minval=1)
periodD = input(3, title="Stoch_D", minval=1)
smoothK = input(1, title="Stoch_Smooth", minval=1)
highLimit = input(80, title="Stoch_HighLimit", minval=1)
lowLimit = input(20, title="Stoch_LowLimit", minval=1)
crossoverSharperDetection = input(title="Sharper Crossover Detection [ON/OFF]", group="Crossover Alerts", type=input.bool, defval=true)
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = sma(k, periodD)
k1 = sma(stoch(close[1], high[1], low[1], periodK), smoothK)
d1 = sma(k1, periodD)


//EMA variables
emaLength= input(200, minval=200, title="EMA_Length")
emaSource = input(close, title="Source")
emaValue = ema(emaSource, emaLength)


//ATR variables
ATR_SL = atr(input(defval=14,title="ATR_SL",type=input.integer))[1]
Multip_ATR_SL = input(defval=2,title="Multip_ATR_SL",type=input.float)
TakeProfitMultiplier = input(defval=1.3,title="TakeProfitMultiplier",type=input.float)
PctStop = input(defval=2, title="% of Risk to Starting Equity Use to Size Positions") / 100



//session variables
//only generate signals within this time frame
session = input("0500-1600:1234567")
t = time(timeframe.period, session)
bgcolor(not na(t) ? color.green : na)



//================================
//Create signals to enter a trade
//================================

//Short only if crossunder of stochastics and close is below EMA
//Long only of crossover of stochastics and close is above EMA

//if crossoverSharperDetection == TRUE, then use stochastics values of previous candles for sharper detection

crossoverBear = crossunder(k, d) and (  (d >= highLimit or k >= highLimit) or (crossoverSharperDetection and ( d1 >= highLimit or k1 >= highLimit ))   ) and  close < emaValue and not na(t) ? avg(k, d) : na
crossoverBull = crossover(k, d) and  (  (d <= lowLimit or k <= lowLimit)   or (crossoverSharperDetection and ( d1 <= lowLimit or k1 <= lowLimit ))   ) and close > emaValue and not na(t) ? avg(k, d)  : na



//================================
//Enter positions routine
//================================

//Long positions
//Set SL to ATR * Multip_ATR_SL below low
//Set TP to TakeProfitMultiplier * ATR above
Longstop_abs =low - ATR_SL * Multip_ATR_SL
Longstop_Pips = (close-Longstop_abs)/syminfo.mintick
LongTP_abs = close+(close - Longstop_abs)*TakeProfitMultiplier
LongTP_Pips = (LongTP_abs - close)/syminfo.mintick


// Uncomment the following lines for debugging
// plot(close, "close")
// plot(LongTP_abs, "LongTP_abs")
// plot(LongTP_Pips, "LongTP_Pips")
// plot(Longstop_abs, "Longstop_abs")
// plot(Longstop_Pips, "Longstop_Pips")


currentEquity = strategy.equity


if crossoverBull 
    LongDiffSL = abs(close - Longstop_abs)
    LongPositionSize = (currentEquity * PctStop) / LongDiffSL
    strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long, qty=LongPositionSize)
    strategy.exit("Exit", from_entry="Enter Long",loss=Longstop_Pips, profit=LongTP_Pips)

    

//Short positions
//Set SL to ATR * Multip_ATR_SL above high
//Set TP to TakeProfitMultiplier * ATR below close
Shortstop_abs =high + ATR_SL * Multip_ATR_SL
Shortstop_Pips = (Shortstop_abs-close)/syminfo.mintick
ShortTP_abs = close - (Shortstop_abs - close)*TakeProfitMultiplier
ShortTP_Pips = (close - ShortTP_abs)/syminfo.mintick


// Uncomment the following lines for debugging
//plot(close, "close")
//plot(Shortstop_abs, "Shortstop_abs")
//plot(Shortstop_Pips, "Shortstop_Pips")
//plot(ShortTP_abs, "ShortTP_abs")
//plot(ShortTP_Pips, "ShortTP_Pips")


if crossoverBear
    ShortDiffSL = abs(Shortstop_abs - close)
    ShortPositionSize = (currentEquity * PctStop) / ShortDiffSL
    strategy.entry("Enter Short", strategy.short, qty = ShortPositionSize)
    strategy.exit("Exit Short", from_entry="Enter Short",loss=Shortstop_Pips, profit=ShortTP_Pips)



//================================
//Plots
//================================

plot(emaValue, color=color.red, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="EMA")
plot(Longstop_abs,"ATR Long Stop Loss1", style=plot.style_cross, linewidth = 2)
plot(Shortstop_abs,"ATR Short Stop Loss1", style=plot.style_cross, linewidth = 2)

plotshape(crossoverBear, title='Stochastic-BEAR', style=shape.triangledown, text='', location=location.top,offset=0, color=color.orange, textcolor=color.black, size=size.normal) 
plotshape(crossoverBull, title='Stochastic-BULL', style=shape.triangleup, text='', location=location.bottom, offset=0, color=color.lime, textcolor=color.black, size=size.normal) 

plotshape(crossoverBear, title='Stochastic-BEAR', style=shape.triangledown, text='SELL', location=location.abovebar,offset=0, color=color.orange, textcolor=color.black, size=size.small) 
plotshape(crossoverBull, title='Stochastic-BULL', style=shape.triangleup, text='BUY', location=location.belowbar, offset=0, color=color.lime, textcolor=color.black, size=size.small)
```

The strategy is the following:
At the close of the bar, when a crossover signal happens, I enter the trade:

1. put the SL to 2x ATR of the low of that candle (blue crosses)
2. put TP to 1.3 times that value above the close

Like in the following example:

[image]

As you can see, in this example it worked correctly. The exit was exactly at the value of LongTP_abs.

Here are two examples, where the SL was triggered correctly:

[image]
[image]

However, there are also many examples where it is wrong:

1. SL was triggered wrongly:
   [image]
2. TP was triggered too early:
   [image]
3. SL and TP are triggered wrongly:
   [image]

On all pictures you can see the date. Thus, you should be able to reproduce it on the 5min timeframe auf AUDJPY.

Comment: Q: 1) do you use `close` in `Longstop_Pips = (close-Longstop_abs)/syminfo.mintick`. Maybe it is better to use `strategy.position_avg_price` instead? 2) Your `strategy.exist` accepts loss & profit values only when `crossoverBull` is true, i.e. new `Longstop_Pips` values is not affecting on the stoploss level.

Comment: @AndreyD Thanks for your reply. I tried to replace `close` with `strategy.position_avg_price` but it still does not work. The weird thing is, that for many trades it is working correctly, but sometimes it is just completely wrong.

And yes I only want to open a position, if `crossoverBull` is true (this variable is set when Stochastics is having a crossover). Thus, `Longstop_Pips` should only be relevant when I open the trade, or?

Comment: Would it be possible to get the full code? Or at least a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @vitruvius: I added the full code and also some more explantions / examples to the answer under the section "EDIT 31.08.2022"

Comment: "Thus, Longstop_Pips should only be relevant when I open the trade, or?" - do you want this behaviour? Fix the SL level with `Longstop_Pips` value only when the position must been opened ?

Comment: @AndreyD: Yes, Longstop_Pips shall only be calculated when the position is opened and then the stop value shall stay fixed until it is either hit or if the position is closed once TP is hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the input from Andrey, I actually found the reason. I only had to add the position size to the if statement of my own version:

```
if crossoverBull and strategy.position_size == 0
    LongDiffSL = abs(close - Longstop_abs)
    LongPositionSize = (initialCapital * PctStop) / LongDiffSL
    strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long, qty=LongPositionSize)
    strategy.exit("Exit", from_entry="Enter Long",loss=Longstop_Pips, profit=LongTP_Pips)
```

Because otherwise the exit loss and profit values are reset, if there is another crossoverBull trigger while the position is open. This explains also why it worked sometimes. If the TP was hit very quickly without a new crossoverBull Signal, then the TP was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've used strategy.position_avg_price for SL/TP levels calculations and make `strategy.exit` calls on every bar because it needs to take into account new SL/TP values (if the exit is exists no new exit placed and, but current existing exit with specified id are MODIFIED). And have added some debug plots with current SL/TP levels for easy to debug.
Try this version:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Stochastic Cross Alarm Strategy", default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=10, initial_capital=1000, overlay = true, format=format.price, precision=2)


//Stochastics variables
periodK = input(14, title="Stoch_K", minval=1)
periodD = input(3, title="Stoch_D", minval=1)
smoothK = input(1, title="Stoch_Smooth", minval=1)
highLimit = input(80, title="Stoch_HighLimit", minval=1)
lowLimit = input(20, title="Stoch_LowLimit", minval=1)
crossoverSharperDetection = input(title="Sharper Crossover Detection [ON/OFF]", group="Crossover Alerts", type=input.bool, defval=true)
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = sma(k, periodD)
k1 = sma(stoch(close[1], high[1], low[1], periodK), smoothK)
d1 = sma(k1, periodD)


//EMA variables
emaLength= input(200, minval=200, title="EMA_Length")
emaSource = input(close, title="Source")
emaValue = ema(emaSource, emaLength)


//ATR variables
ATR_SL = atr(input(defval=14,title="ATR_SL",type=input.integer))[1]
Multip_ATR_SL = input(defval=2,title="Multip_ATR_SL",type=input.float)
TakeProfitMultiplier = input(defval=1.3,title="TakeProfitMultiplier",type=input.float)
PctStop = input(defval=2, title="% of Risk to Starting Equity Use to Size Positions") / 100



//session variables
//only generate signals within this time frame
session = input("0500-1600:1234567")
t = time(timeframe.period, session)
bgcolor(not na(t) ? color.green : na)



//================================
//Create signals to enter a trade
//================================

//Short only if crossunder of stochastics and close is below EMA
//Long only of crossover of stochastics and close is above EMA

//if crossoverSharperDetection == TRUE, then use stochastics values of previous candles for sharper detection

crossoverBear = crossunder(k, d) and (  (d >= highLimit or k >= highLimit) or (crossoverSharperDetection and ( d1 >= highLimit or k1 >= highLimit ))   ) and  close < emaValue and not na(t) ? avg(k, d) : na
crossoverBull = crossover(k, d) and  (  (d <= lowLimit or k <= lowLimit)   or (crossoverSharperDetection and ( d1 <= lowLimit or k1 <= lowLimit ))   ) and close > emaValue and not na(t) ? avg(k, d)  : na



//================================
//Enter positions routine
//================================

//Long positions
//Set SL to ATR * Multip_ATR_SL below low
//Set TP to TakeProfitMultiplier * ATR above
Longstop_abs =low - ATR_SL * Multip_ATR_SL

avgPosPrice = strategy.position_avg_price

float Longstop_Pips = na
float LongTP_abs = na
float LongTP_Pips = na
if strategy.position_size>0
    Longstop_Pips := (avgPosPrice-Longstop_abs)/syminfo.mintick
    LongTP_abs := avgPosPrice+(avgPosPrice - Longstop_abs)*TakeProfitMultiplier
    LongTP_Pips := (LongTP_abs - avgPosPrice)/syminfo.mintick


// Uncomment the following lines for debugging
// plot(close, "close")
plot(LongTP_abs, "LongTP_abs", style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.rgb(42, 235, 67))
plot(na(Longstop_Pips) ? na : Longstop_abs, "LongSL_abs", style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.rgb(223, 75, 166))
// plot(LongTP_Pips, "LongTP_Pips")
// plot(Longstop_abs, "Longstop_abs")
// plot(Longstop_Pips, "Longstop_Pips")


currentEquity = strategy.equity


if crossoverBull 
    LongDiffSL = abs(close - Longstop_abs)
    LongPositionSize = (currentEquity * PctStop) / LongDiffSL
    strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long, qty=LongPositionSize)

strategy.exit("Exit", from_entry="Enter Long",loss=Longstop_Pips, profit=LongTP_Pips)

    

//Short positions
//Set SL to ATR * Multip_ATR_SL above high
//Set TP to TakeProfitMultiplier * ATR below close
Shortstop_abs = high + ATR_SL * Multip_ATR_SL
float Shortstop_Pips = na
float ShortTP_abs = na
float ShortTP_Pips = na
if strategy.position_size<0
    Shortstop_Pips := (Shortstop_abs-avgPosPrice)/syminfo.mintick
    ShortTP_abs := avgPosPrice - (Shortstop_abs - avgPosPrice)*TakeProfitMultiplier
    ShortTP_Pips := (avgPosPrice - ShortTP_abs)/syminfo.mintick


// Uncomment the following lines for debugging
//plot(close, "close")
//plot(Shortstop_abs, "Shortstop_abs")
//plot(Shortstop_Pips, "Shortstop_Pips")
plot(ShortTP_abs, "ShortTP_abs", style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.rgb(42, 235, 67))
plot(na(Shortstop_Pips) ? na : Shortstop_abs, "ShortSL_abs", style = plot.style_linebr, color = color.rgb(223, 75, 166))
//plot(ShortTP_Pips, "ShortTP_Pips")


if crossoverBear
    ShortDiffSL = abs(Shortstop_abs - close)
    ShortPositionSize = (currentEquity * PctStop) / ShortDiffSL
    strategy.entry("Enter Short", strategy.short, qty = ShortPositionSize)
strategy.exit("Exit Short", from_entry="Enter Short",loss=Shortstop_Pips, profit=ShortTP_Pips)



//================================
//Plots
//================================

plot(emaValue, color=color.red, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="EMA")
plot(Longstop_abs,"ATR Long Stop Loss1", style=plot.style_cross, linewidth = 2)
plot(Shortstop_abs,"ATR Short Stop Loss1", style=plot.style_cross, linewidth = 2)

plotshape(crossoverBear, title='Stochastic-BEAR', style=shape.triangledown, text='', location=location.top,offset=0, color=color.orange, textcolor=color.black, size=size.normal) 
plotshape(crossoverBull, title='Stochastic-BULL', style=shape.triangleup, text='', location=location.bottom, offset=0, color=color.lime, textcolor=color.black, size=size.normal) 

plotshape(crossoverBear, title='Stochastic-BEAR', style=shape.triangledown, text='SELL', location=location.abovebar,offset=0, color=color.orange, textcolor=color.black, size=size.small) 
plotshape(crossoverBull, title='Stochastic-BULL', style=shape.triangleup, text='BUY', location=location.belowbar, offset=0, color=color.lime, textcolor=color.black, size=size.small)
```

Comment: I just fully understood your code. Actually the SL and TP shall not be changed while the position is open. Instead, the SL and TP shall stay at the values when the position was opened.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help. Your code finally took me to the solution below :)